# Spring Rest - set headers without request body

Tags: java, spring, rest

I need to set an authorization header in the REST call in my client, but the web service doesn't expect a request body. How would I send this?

Right now I have this, which I know is wrong:

```
HttpEntity<String> response = new HttpEntity<String>(authToken, headers);
restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
TransactionResponse transactionResponse = restTemplate.postForObject(uri, response, TransactionResponse.class);
return transactionResponse;
```

Comment: If your web service doesn't expect a request body, why are you sending a POST request to begin with?

Comment: Makoto, what should I be using instead?

Comment: Surely the documentation for what you're interfacing specifies the endpoint resource *and* the HTTP verb it expects.  I would venture "GET" would be what you want to use, but I wouldn't know without having seen the endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

To add the authentication header, can't you just add it to the headers?

```
headers.add("Authentication", authToken);
```

I think (but have not tried) that you could give the type parameter for the entity as `Void`:

```
HttpEntity<Void> response = new HttpEntity<>(null, headers);
```

Bear in mind that the actual header name needed might be different from the one I used above.